# Prevent spring session override in the same war

Tags: spring, session, spring-security, token, spring-security-oauth2

Let's say I have a WAR which has a front-end in JSP, and includes a JAR with a REST API.

I have one `spring-security.xml` in which multiple authenticationProviders are configured.

The problem I'm facing is as follows:

- A user (user1) is logged in into the JSP-front-end through basic authentication (localhost/app1)
- On the same browser a different user (user2) logs in into a different front-end with a oauth token (localhost/app2)
- Whenever this token is used for a REST call (localhost/rest), the user (user1) from the JSP-front-end (app1) is overridden by user2.

For the REST API, `create-session="never"` is enabled. But the user from the session of the JSP is overridden anyways.

I'm using Spring 3.2.15 and Spring Security 3.2.9

Relevants parts of the `spring-security.xml`:

```
<!-- The configuration for the rest-api -->
<security:http pattern="/rest/**" create-session="never" use-expressions="true"
               entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint">
    <security:anonymous enabled="false" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/**" access="permitAll" method="OPTIONS" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:custom-filter ref="CORSFilter" position="FIRST" />
    <security:custom-filter ref="um-rest-resource-server" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
</security:http>

<!-- Other configration for the other endpoints (not under /rest/) ... -->

<oauth2:resource-server id="um-rest-resource-server" resource-id="um-rest-resource-server" token-services-ref="tokenVerifier" />

<bean id="tokenVerifier" class="be.healthconnect.iam.oauth2.verifier.TokenVerifier"></bean>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the frontends are in the same war, this is what is intended to happen.

But there is a way you could give a chance to.  If your REST app2 is in fact fully stateless,  try setting create session strategy to stateless this way: `create-session="stateless"`.

While setting session creation strategy to stateless,  `SecurityContextHolder` won't be even checked to look for a valid session, and it won`t be called too to save the succesfull authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser has to send the session cookie for all requests to your server. Your second call (to `localhost/app2`) contains the session cookie and Spring Security uses this session (and changes your user).

There are some solutions, but if you need no session at all, you could tell Spring Security to ignore the session cookie in the request by setting `create-session="stateless"`, see [Spring Security Reference](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.x/reference/htmlsingle/#nsa-http-attributes):

> - **create-session** Controls the eagerness with which an HTTP session is created by Spring Security classes. Options include:
>
>   - `always` - Spring Security will proactively create a session if one does not exist.
>   - `ifRequired` - Spring Security will only create a session only if one is required (default value).
>   - `never` - Spring Security will never create a session, but will make use of one if the application does.
>   - `stateless` - Spring Security will not create a session and ignore the session for obtaining a Spring `Authentication`.

If you need a session, other solutions are:

- separat browser sessions
- separat WAR files
- URL rewriting for session ID
- disallow to login again